# GWT: debug id vs normal id

Tags: gwt

What is the advantage of setting the debug id instead of setting normal id on an element:

```
button.ensureDebugId("myDebugId");
button.getElement().setId("myId");
```

If I take time to set some id anyway, why not to make it permanent? Why debug id?

Answer (score 3):

When using the debug id you are making sure the the compile permutations used in production environment will have a lower file size, because it won't have any debug information. The debug id should be used only for development.

This is important for the end users, because your app will load faster.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of using debug id's is that it makes it clear to developers of your project that these id's will **only** be used for Selenium (or other DOM-based approach) testing. It makes it clear that they should not be relied upon for the production application.

Ideally, you'd use 2 different GWT modules (one for production, one for testing):

`Production.gwt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
        "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <entry-point class='com.mycompany.MyApp'/>
</module>
```

`Testing.gwt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
        "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name='com.mycompany.Produdction'/>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.debug.Debug"/>
</module>
```

This ensures that debug id's will only be present in the DOM during your test phase and won't pollute your production app.